# Best method to convert NSStrings to enums

Tags: objective-c, ios, enums, nsstring

Lets say I have this enum defined (from Apple's UIKit framework):

```
typedef enum {
    UITextAutocorrectionTypeDefault,
    UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo,
    UITextAutocorrectionTypeYes,
} UITextAutocorrectionType;
```

and I have a simple string with "UITextAutocorrectionTypeDefault" value. In my case, this string is coming from a JSON object, but it doesn't matter.

What would be the best way for me to convert the string into the proper enum value so I can set a property in the class? I know Obj-C can't just convert the value directly (like you can do with Java or C#), and in my case I have lots of enums, and ones that may be created at a later time. Are there any automatic or semi-automatic ways of doing this, other than having to create a mapping dictionary manually?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `C` (read `Objective-C`) there is no way to do this other than manually mapping the values. The enum just defines constant values that can not be converted to or from a string at runtime like  they can in `C#` or `Java` which treats them as objects.

You can how ever [stringify](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html) the values at compile time.

Comment: Thanks. stringify looks interesting, I'll look more into it.

Comment: Not a good answer: "you can however ... (link to something obscure, which doesn't obviously map to the question, and I won't say how)"

Comment: So you don't agree with a correct answer plus another option they can explore to stringify the values?